# Rails: Generating Tables based on groups of related database records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, group-by, grouping

I have a collection of records in my database that I want to print out to separate tables based on the record date.

So I already have the following (in Haml, fyi):

```
%table
  %tr
    %th Name
    %th Type
    %th Total Hits
  - for record in @records
    %tr{ :class => cycle('odd','even') }
      %td= record.name
      %td= record.target_type
      %td= record.outbound + record.detail + record.custom + record.dynamic
```

At the moment, it displays all my records in the same table. `record.recorded_on` contains the date for my records.  I want to generate separate tables, like the one above, for each day that contains all the records for that day.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `recorded_on` is a date, and not a DateTime:

```
@records = Record.all.group_by(&:recorded_on)
```

If it is a DateTime:

```
@records = Record.all.group_by { |record| record.recorded_on.to_date }
```

Now `@records` contains some nested arrays.  Stick your table haml above in a partial named `_record_table.html.haml`.  Be sure to change `@records` to a local variable `records` so it can be swapped out for each partial render.

Now your haml template looks like this:

```
- @records.each do |records_for_one_day|
  = render :partial => 'render_table', :locals => { :records => records_for_one_day }
```

Comment: Thanks - exactly what I needed.  Out of curiosity, though, what does the "&:" mean in @records = Record.all.group_by(&:recorded_on)?

Comment: &: is something called Symbol#to_proc, it's a way to abbreviate calls to methods with blocks. So, group_by(&:recorded_on) has the same effect as: group_by { |record| record.recorded_on }

Comment: Max is right.  In the second example I put up there I had to use the longhand because I wanted to additionally process result a bit, which the shorthand version has no support for.